# setTimeout in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, use-effect

I'm trying to change the style of an element within setTimeout and useEffect.

Here is how the code looks like

```
In home.js: 
useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        // change styles  for 'frontenddevelopment'
        changeStyles1();
    },1000)

    // changeStyles for 'i love frontend'
    changeStyles2()
},[])
```

I found that after the home page is rendered if I navigate to other pages and come back to home page, changesStyles1() will be called again and animation will run again. What should I do to avoid calling setTimeout() again when I navigate back to home page from other pages.

You will notices that changeStyle2 won't be animated again if I navigate from home page to other page and then back to home page. And this is the effect I want.

My website is hosted on [netlify](https://portfolio-test-1.netlify.app/)
My code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Beemo-007/pen/GRZQzjK)

Comment: I suppose you could track in some global app state if/when the home page has mounted for the "first" time. But when should the animation be run again? 5 minutes? Next day? Next hard reload? Never? What have you tried and what are your expectations for behavior?

Comment: Can you give the rest of the code?

Comment: You don't have any condition for checking if the styles already changed...

Comment: The animation should never run again except for the hard reload. I'm trying to make a spa, and there is no state changes in home page. I suppose this animation should only run once when the page is loaded for the first time.

Comment: I think this could be easily solved if already using a global state solution, like Redux, to toggle a "home page rendered" boolean. Be sure to ***not*** persist this state value to localStorage or other long-term app state storage. When the page hard-reloads app state is wiped in memory and (in most solutions/use-cases) re-populated from storage.